# Stub a 'nested' class method that is called by a wrapper method (RSpec Mocks)

Tags: rspec, rspec-mocks

Situation: I want to stub a helper method, so that I can call a method that wraps it and get the stubbed response back.

Code is set up like this:

```
class Thing
  def self.method_one(foo)
    self.method_two(foo, 'some random string')
  end

  def self.method_two(foo, bar)
    self.method_three(foo, bar, 'no meaning')
  end

  def self.method_three(foo, bar, baz)
    "#{foo} is #{bar} with #{baz}"
  end
end
```

I'm trying to mock `.method_three` so that I can call `.method_one` and have it ultimately call `.method_three`'s double instead of the real deal:

```
it "uses the mock for .method_three" do
  response_double = 'This is a different string'
  thing = class_double("Thing", :method_three => response_double).as_stubbed_const

  response = thing.method_one('Hi')
  expect(response).to eq(response_double)
end
```

The error I'm getting:

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<ClassDouble(Thing) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :method_one with ("Hi")
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Feels like I'm missing an obvious step, but despite my best efforts I haven't been able to find an example of this or a question that asks anything comparable.

(Note: if it matters, this is not a Rails project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use RSpec's `allow(...)` to stub the intermediate method.  This is also useful for testing logic flow or for mocking third-party services in tests.

For example:

`expected_response = 'This is a different string'
allow(Thing).to receive(:method_three).and_return(expected_response)`

Then `expect(Thing.method_one('Hi')).to eq(expected_response)` should pass.

See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs for more information on stubbing methods.

Comment: Perfect! I'm using this to mock a response from a third party API. Since my `.method_three` actually returns a Faraday connection that I then call another method on, I needed to use `receive_message_chain`. 

My actual code is this (may this help some future googler): 

`allow(FaradayConnection).to receive_message_chain(:connection, :get).and_return(expected_faraday_response)`.